# How to act against old, highly upvoted but also off-topic questions?

Tags: discussion, scope, old-questions

Few days ago, I came across [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2639866/jpeg-image-with-alpha-channel-on-website) bumped to home page because someone added a new answer.

The question itself has nothing to do with programming, even though it has a lot of up-votes, and many answers are also up-voted.

I believe the reason behind it is that SO standards has been changed and improved through the time, hence the question wasn't closed long time ago and was appreciated by votes when it first appeared.

I took the decision to flag it as off-topic.

My flag now aged away, so should I just wait until I can flag it again? Or should I use *in need for moderator intervention* flag? Or should I just drop it down because it's an old question and highly up-voted?

Comment: Downvote, flag, move on? You can take it to SOCVR to see if you get more traction there.

Answer (score -4):

This question was asked *7 years, 9 months ago*.

I wouldn't waste much time on old posts, unless they are oddly bad and don't seem to be helpful to anyone. If you think it should be closed, vote to. Otherwise, just move on and focus on more recent posts.

Comment: It is true that they _do_ attract bad quality answers, and dilute the message of what kind of question is actually on topic on SO.